# Data becomes unreadable after BCP out with -t"|"

Tags: t-sql, bcp

This one is blowing my mind a bit.  I am able to BCP OUT a file fine with just -c but I need the data to be pipe delimited so I include -t"|" and the data becomes all special characters.  Here's the code:

```
SET @bcpsql =  
    ' cd C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\ & BCP.EXE ' +  
    ' "SELECT * FROM wire" queryout' +  
    ' "C:\WIRE_'+@dte+'.txt" -T -c -t"|" >> "C:\mantas\log.txt"';  
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @bcpsql
```

If I put -t"^|" it will export fine but all the delimiters become ^|.  So, somehow the pipe is throwing something off.  Has anyone encountered something like this?

Comment: Have you tried -T<space>|, so not escaping the pipe with ^ but using a space between -T and the pipe character?

Comment: When i use -t | I get the error:

The syntax of the command is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You need the space between the parameter and the pipe, but you also need the double quotes.

use -t "|" 
(-T[space]"|")